# How do I create textured landscape in low poly style?

Tags: unity, textures, low-poly

I'm trying to create something similar to this kind of artistic landscapes in Unity.

I've been from trying to use Unity's terrain system and Gaia to making it in Blender; no matter how I can't figure out how it's made; how to texture it afterwards.

I'd be thankful is someone can point me in the starting direction.

Thanks !

[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: How do your attempts so far differ from what you want?

Comment: I can't get to 'paint' on the actual mesh; I don't know how to do it (or where to get started)

Comment: See the side of the roads and the road to the light house; how is it done ?

Comment: So your question is "how do I draw a road onto a terrain"? Have you reviewed [previous questions on this topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=road+terrain) for some ideas & starting points? If you've tried implementing one of these methods and run into a block, tell us about that issue in detail and we may be able to help you solve it.

Comment: well no, my question is more like "how they did get this look ? by using terrains ? by using low poly and texturing ?"

Comment: I don't see that those are mutually exclusive options. Many games will use both terrain AND additional textured polygons to create a particular look. Have you tried laying a polygonal road over your terrain to mimic this look?

Comment: Indeed I tried; the problem is that i don't know how to 'paint' it the way i want; look at the lighthouse path, it's not a mesh, it's painted, somehow ?

Comment: Hmm... it sure looks like a mesh to me - especially the sharp hexagonal shape. I'd guess they've split the mesh & texture into a central "fill" with strips of border polygons along the edges, [similar to the UV unwrapping shown in Wind Waker in this previous Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/163550/39518). Are you asking about how to achieve the "painterly" brushy texture art style  used along these edge strips, to blend the road with its surroundings? If not, can you describe in more detail what you mean by "paint" in this instance?

Comment: Thats it ! Your link (haha) pointed me to this video which shows how it is done. https://youtu.be/axEby3JmIFw. Thank you so much !

Comment: Excellent! If you can write up the solution you found as an answer, I'd say it would be well worth some upvotes. :) Be sure to describe the method used in the video, just in case the link is unavailable.